# Check database through PHP for new record with jQuery timer?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, timer

I have a small messaging system (about 20 users, usually max 4 concurrent) wired up with php/wordpress, mysql, jQuery.

When users send a message to each other, it simply goes to tbl_messages, and gets refreshed on page load.

I was thinking of making this work like a real "chat" interface.

Is it feasible to:

1. Set a session variable to 0
2. Run jQuery interval timer, with AJAX run PHP function every 10secs
3. PHP function checks MySql table for changes. If there is a change, set session variable to 1
4. If jQuery interval timer sees session var = 1, run a different PHP function (through AJAX) that returns new data, append it to the messages div, then set session variable to 0 again.

My application at its current state is **a given**, so I'm not allowed to re-design it from the ground up with a more efficient architecture.

Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to write a message application, I can recomment looking into web-sockets, you don't have to do ajax on the background and wait every x amount to run the query. It will be more complicated at the beginning but at the end you are going to build a better and scalable solution.